# Unable to run downloaded jar from other jar

Tags: java, jar

I currently have the following problem:

I have created a **updater** jar from which a **client** jar is downloaded and placed in some directory (just somewhere on the disk, not associated with the directory of the updater jar). I use the following code the run the client jar from the updater:

```
private void startApplication() {

    String url = getFilePath()+"client.jar";

    URL parsedURL = null;
    try {
        parsedURL = new File(url).toURI().toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{parsedURL}, getClass().getClassLoader());
    Class<?> cl = null;
    try {
        cl = Class.forName("org.myApp.client.mainPackage.Main", true, loader);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        loader = null;
    }

    Class<? extends Application> runClass = cl.asSubclass(Application.class);
    // Avoid Class.newInstance, for it is evil.
    Constructor<? extends Application> ctor = null;
    try {
        ctor = runClass.getConstructor();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Application doRun = null;
    try {
        doRun = ctor.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        doRun.start(primaryStage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This code seems to work, because the Main of the client.jar gets runned. However, after its Main is started, I get an exception from the client jar. The Main from the client jar tries to load a FXML file in the upper pane. This is the exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.myApp.client.lockscreen.LockscreenController when loading a FXML file
```

I do not know what triggers this error. The client jar just runs as should be, when I run it standalone.

**Do I need to load all classes from the client jar from the updater jar?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that the class cannot be found because it is not on your classpath.

This depends on how you build your application (Ant, Maven etc), since this determines how the location of the .jar file is known, and where the .jar file is.

If you are using an IDE, there would usually be some sort of Libraries placeholder in which you define .jars that you are dependent upon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am loading the jar dynamically, so it is not yet present when I build the updater jar. Moreover, I don't want to add it to the libraries, because I want the updater to open it from a directory on the disk.

Comment: In that case you need to be sure you are using the correct form of URI/URL and be clear about relative or absolute addressing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with this. The client jar is running correctly, only the screen will not open, because it can not find the controller class. Maybe you could update your answer?

Comment: Sorry - I just meant, it may depend on what you get back from your getFilePath() call, and where the .jar file is relative to that.  Also, does it contain a "/" at the end?

Comment: This is the load exception I get, where you can see the path of the loaded jar: `javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/MyApp/client.jar!/org/myApp/client/lockscreen/Lockscreen.fxml:15`

Answer (score 3):

Everybody thanks for your help. I was able to fix it like this (thanks Jool, you will get all the credits):

I downloaded and runned the client jar, assuming it would have its own references. However, as Jool said, I had to add the director to the class path. What I did wrong, was that I added the directory, and not the Jar file. You have to add the JAR file too ! I did that with this code:

```
public void addPath(String s) throws Exception {

    File f = new File(s);
    URI u = f.toURI();
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class<URLClassLoader> urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
    Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[]{u.toURL()});

}
```

And then I just called `addPath(url)` before running the client jar.